# PDEs - F.O.L. M.o.C. - Theory: Back checking (non-hom.) solution to Transport Eq. leads to an issue!

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am having trouble differentiating integrals in $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
This particular problem requires the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the Chain Rule in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
$$---------------------------------------$$
Allow me to set the context. We have a First Order Linear (Non-homogeneous) PDE:
$$F\big(x,\{\partial_i\}_{i\in\{1,...n\}}\big)u = \bigg(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(x)\cdot\partial_i \bigg)u - \lambda_{n+1}(x) = 0$$
with boundary condition:
$$u\big|_{\partial U}(x)\equiv g(x).$$
$$---------------------------------------$$
The instance PDE is called the *"(Non-hom.) Transport Equation"*. And looks like:
$$u_t+\boldsymbol b\cdot Du = f. \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }(\star)$$
$$---------------------------------------$$
Painstakingly understanding and applying the *Method of Characteristics*, we come across the solution:
$$u(\boldsymbol x,t) = g(\boldsymbol x- \boldsymbol bt) + \int_0^tf( \boldsymbol x+(s-t) \boldsymbol b,s)ds$$
$$---------------------------------------$$
And my problem is: For $u$ to be a "solution", it must satisfy $(\star)$. 
But, how does one compute $\partial_t u$ and $\partial_i u$? (The term with $g$ I don't care about). Surely it helps to see also:
$$\boldsymbol x, \boldsymbol b\in\mathbb{R}^n\text{ and }s,t\in \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: Messing around with special cases, I managed to come up with the postulate: $$\partial_t \circ \int_0^t f(x,s,t)ds = \partial_t\big[\int_0^t \partial_t f(x,s,t)ds\big].$$ Which leads me to: $$\partial_t u = -b\cdot D f(x,t).$$ Not sure if that works or about the other case though.

Comment: [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: @Sal On to proving Leibniz it seems! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you denote with $Du $ taking the gradient $\nabla u$. But first, define \begin{align} \boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) &:= \boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol b t \\ 
\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s) &:= \boldsymbol x + (s-t) \boldsymbol b\end{align}
such that you can formulate the solution as
$$u(\boldsymbol x, t) = g\big (\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) \big) + \int_0^t f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s), s\big) \mathrm d s. $$
Let's take the gradient now (and assume that $f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t), s\big)$ is continuosly differentiable in the first argument). Furthermore, I am going to use index notation to not have to worry about the order of multiplication etc.
\begin{align} \nabla u(\boldsymbol x, t) = \partial^x_i u(\boldsymbol x, t) &=
\partial^x_i \Bigg[ g\big (\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) \big) + \int_0^t f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s), s\big) \mathrm d s \Bigg] \\
&\overset{\text{Chain rule}}{=} \partial_j^y g\big (\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) \big) \frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_i}+ \int_0^t \partial_j^h f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t), s\big) \frac{\partial h_j}{\partial x_i} \mathrm d s \\
&= \partial_j^y g\big (\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) \big) \delta_{ij} + \int_0^t \partial_j^h f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s), s\big) \delta_{ij} \mathrm d s \\
&= \partial_i^y g\big (\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) \big) + \int_0^t \partial_i^h f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s), s\big)  \mathrm d s
 \end{align}

Now the temporal derivative, for which we require the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), as mentioned in the comments by Sal.
\begin{align}
\partial_t u (\boldsymbol x, t) &\overset{\text{Chain rule}}{=} \partial_j^y g\big (\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) \big) \frac{\partial y_j}{\partial t}+ \partial_t \int_0^t f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s), s\big) \mathrm d s \\
&= \partial_j^y g\big (\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) \big) (-b_j ) + f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, t), t\big) \frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d t} t - (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, 0), 0\big) \frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d t} 0 + \int_0^t \partial_t f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s), s\big) \mathrm d s \\
&\overset{\text{Chain rule}}{=} -b_i \partial_i^y g\big (\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) \big) + f\big (\boldsymbol x + (t -t) \boldsymbol b, t\big) + \int_0^t \partial^h_i f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s), s\big) \frac{\partial h_i}{\partial t} \mathrm d s \\
&= -b_i \partial_i^y g\big (\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) \big) + f\big (\boldsymbol x, t\big) + \int_0^t \partial^h_i f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s), s\big) (-b_i) \mathrm d s \\
&= -b_i \partial_i^y g\big (\boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol x, t) \big) + f\big (\boldsymbol x, t\big) -b_i \int_0^t \partial^h_i f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s), s\big) \mathrm d s
\end{align}

Rewrite $\boldsymbol b \cdot \nabla u(\boldsymbol x, t) = b_i \partial_i^x u(\boldsymbol x, t)$ and put things together; you see that the PDE is exactly satsified.

Regarding the "boundary condition", this looks to me more like a initial condition (what should be the boundary of $\boldsymbol x \in \mathbb R^n$?):
$$u(\boldsymbol x, t_0 = 0) \overset{!}{=} g(x) = g(\boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol b * 0) + \int_0^0 f\big (\boldsymbol h (\boldsymbol x, t, s), s\big) \mathrm d s $$

Comment: The notation I learned separated the gradient into spatial and temporal so yes essentially $D$ is $\nabla$ without $\partial_t$. $x=(x,t)$ is an abuse of notation that just happens idk. It is good to reaffirm that the spatial derivatives skip past the integral since the limits only involve $t$. And I've noted your explicit use of Liebniz. Thanks for the help this was a brick wall haha!